# How to get stored path of uploaded image in Vue / October

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, octobercms

I have an app that uses October CMS to store images in a database. When I add the image in October, I use the following method:

Which gives me the image_path in October:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'image' => ['System\Models\File']
];

public function getImagePathAttribute(){
    return $this->image->path;
}
```

http://localhost/bit703/module6/storage/app/uploads/public/60b/6cb/8d3/60b6cb8d39915448328696.jpg

The problem I'm having is that when I upload my image from Vue, it's storing it without the path of where the image is being stored, causing errors in the October backend.

Is there a way to find that image path and add it to my request in Vue? My Vue code looks as follows:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      apiRequest: new this.$request({
        name: '',
        description: '',
        tags: '',
        filter: '',
        file: '',
        response: '',
        image_path: '',
      }),
      errorMessage: '',
      successMessage: '',
      submitted: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      const bodyFormData = new FormData();
      bodyFormData.append('name', 'iamge1');
      bodyFormData.append('description', 'An image');
      bodyFormData.append('tags', 'Winter');
      bodyFormData.append('filter', '1977');
      bodyFormData.append('user_id', 2);
      bodyFormData.append('file', this.file);
      bodyFormData.append('image_path', '???');
      this.onFileChange();
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/bit703/module6/api/v1/images',
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          this.resposne = response;
        });
    },
    onFileChange(e) {
      const image = e.target.files[0];
      this.file = image;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: can you please share how you are storing image

Comment: You also have a typo. `this.resposne = response` should be `this.response = response`. But yeah, we'll need to see the code that processes your upload endpoint `/api/v1/images` to see what your Vue request is missing that is preventing October from processing it correctly. Side note, take a look at using Winter CMS instead ;)